# SSRS Create temporary datetime table updated with 15 minute interval - parameter not showing

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, parameters, intervals, temp-tables

I'm creating a temporary datetime table with 15 minutes increment with the following code in SSRS:

```
--declare @Id varchar(20), @startdate datetime,@enddate datetime
--set @ID = 'J00000041'
--set @startdate = '20210601'
--set @enddate = '20210630';

create table #tempcalendar ([dispdate] [datetime], intervaldate [datetime],intervaltime [datetime])


    while @StartDate <= @EndDate+1
        begin
            insert into #tempcalendar values(@StartDate, convert(varchar,@StartDate,110),   convert(varchar(5),@StartDate,108) )
            set (@StartDate) = dateadd(minute,15,@StartDate)
            
        end
```

One of the parameters doesn't appear in the Define Query Parameters dialogue box when I try to run it in SSRS and I get the message 'Must declare the scalar variable' error. I've pinpointed the issue where in the code:

```
set @StartDate = dateadd(minute,15,@StartDate)
```

I was able to perform this code in SSMS (which is where I created it initially) however I can't seem to find any information where I might have gone awry in this in SSRS. I've also tried putting parenthesis in @StartDate to show set (@StartDate) = dateadd(minute,15,@StartDate), but that didn't work.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I have seen this before when setting a variable in t-sql that is passed in from SSRS. I think the problem is the SSRS mis-interprets the query. I think I worked round the problem by setting another variable to the passed in value. e.g. `DECLARE @StartDate2 datetime; SET @StartDate2 = @StartDate;` then use `@StartDate2` in the remainder of the query. Also check that every instance of your variable/parameter names are exactly the same, they are case sensitive. If you pass in @X but reference @x SSRS will think this is a new parameter.

Comment: That great, I'll add this as an answer so you can accept it and the question will show as answered if other SO users are looking for similar answers in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this before when setting a variable in t-sql that is passed in from SSRS.

I think the problem is the SSRS mis-interprets the query.

I worked around the problem by setting another variable to the passed in value.
e.g.

```
DECLARE @StartDate2 datetime
SET @StartDate2 = @StartDate
```

.. then use `@StartDate2` in the remainder of the query.

Also check that every instance of your variable/parameter names are exactly the same, they are case sensitive. If you pass in `@X` but reference `@x` SSRS will think this is a new parameter.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS expects to be able to return metadata on the SQL in the dataset. This is how it determines the column names and data types for you. This is also why you can only have one `select` statement in the dataset.

You can wrap your query in a stored procedure. SSRS can call the procedure and pass in the parameters. The procedure should have one `select` statement that returns the results for the report to handle. The procedure can be as complex as you need it to be and abstracts that code from being embedded in the report.